# Are there any online question bank of mathematics questions?

Tags: mathematical-pedagogy, online

I know Dr. Martin Greenhow and his team of Brunel University London have developed online questions and I have used some of these at the following url: http://maths-for-all.co.uk/engineering-mathematics/ Are there any other online questions like these that students can use for testing themselves at these difficult times for them at home?

Comment: What educational level are you interested in (pre-school, primary, secondary, tertiary, graduate)?  What math subjects?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. First-year of an undergraduate mathematics programme such as mathematical techniques, linear algebra and some proof related work. Thanks

Comment: Ah, you may need more advanced and specific questions than the OU preparedness quizzes I [posted](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/18159/8660), but I will leave in case helpful for other levels. (I've no affiliation with the OU, but  have seen some of their degree material and thought it was good, as well as fond memories of watching the TV programmes they used to broadcast.)

Comment: Don't have time for a full answer but if you can set it up what you're looking for is [WebWork from the MAA](https://webwork.maa.org/) has a huge database of questions and all the tools you need.

Comment: Thanks for this answer and I will look into this. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The Open University offers [courses](https://www.open.ac.uk/courses/maths) in Mathematics and Associated subjects at a range of levels.

Their site has short, marked quizzes to rate your current ability as well as useful study resources.

1. Select one from Certificate, Diploma and Degree.
2. Choose a combination, mathematics or a combined option.
3. Scroll down and click on the Entry Requirements tab.
4. Select the self-assessed quiz. There are study resources to prepare.
5. Choose which level 1, 2, 3 and complete the quiz!

Comment: Thanks for your answer and this is sort of thing I am looking for but more for a first year undergraduate level. What I looked at was GCSE level.

Comment: @matqkks - For a higher level may consider their site for the [MSc in Mathematics](http://www.open.ac.uk/postgraduate/qualifications/f04) which has the [diagnostic quiz PDF](http://www.open.ac.uk/postgraduate/Courses/media/Courses/Qualification/Infographics/F04_diagnostic-quiz.pdf) with worked solutions.